# SAXParseException cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:filter-chain-map'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Below is my applicationContext-security.xml. I get the folowing error at runtime.

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:filter-chain-map'.
```

xml snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

       <beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
                  <security:filter-chain-map path-type="regex">
                    <security:filter-chain pattern="\A.*assets.*\Z" filters="none"/>
                    <security:filter-chain pattern="\A.*images.*\Z" filters="none"/>
                    <security:filter-chain pattern="\A.*css.*\Z" filters="none"/>
                    <security:filter-chain pattern="\A.*javascript.*\Z" filters="none"/>
                    <security:filter-chain pattern="\A.*mailOwnerReport.*\Z" filters="none"/>
                    <security:filter-chain pattern="\A/.*\Z" filters="httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,pbvfsSecurityFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter"/>
                  </security:filter-chain-map>
            </beans:bean>
/////
</beans:beans>
```

has anyone faced this kinda issue ? Any help?

Comment: I have checked the xsd file nothing wrong with the way you're using filter-chain-map.Seems like its able to find the xsd file.Check if you have spring-security respective jar in the class path.

Comment: Changing the xsd url's to https solved it for me